# Perl LWP::UserAgent request does not return using http1.1 but working fine using http1.0!? Why?

Tags: perl, openssl, lwp, lwp-useragent, http-1.1

I have a very simple script (on a SLES11 system) to send a http1.1 request to a server. This worked fine for a long time. Since a couple of days it stopped working. I have no idea why. After some investigation I found out forcing the script to use http1.0 it is working again. I have no idea why. And I want to know why it is not working in its default http1.1 mode.

I already enabled debugging as much as I know it (see code below). But I do not see anything - my script just hangs. There is no network activity. I neiter see that a socket will be openend (netstat -a), nor I see any incoming traffic form my client on the server. (A "telnet myserver myport" works fine.)

Can someone please help me how to track down this problem? How can I enable more debug to see where the real problem is?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::Debug qw(+);
use LWP::UserAgent;

# Workaround: forcing http1.0 instead of using http1.1, it works again!
use LWP::Protocol::https10 ();
LWP::Protocol::implementor('https', 'LWP::Protocol::https10');
# EO workaround

my $ua        = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0 );
my $response  = $ua->request(
    POST 'https://myuser:mypassword@myserver:8888/service/myservice',
    Connection   => 'close',     # Edit: added, see comments below
    Content_Type => 'text/xml',
    Content      => '... my content ...'
);
```

$ua->request() does not return! I need to kill/^C the script!

Edit: ok, no one seems to have an idea how to continue. So I startet debugging it using perl debugger.

```
LWP::UserAgent::post(/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:418):
418:        return $self->request( HTTP::Request::Common::POST( @parameters ), @suff );
```

So I can see it is not returning from request().

Anyway, due to the fact that `LWP::UserAgent` calls `HTTP::Request::Common` I changed my example code above back to use `HTTP::Request::Common` to skip that step while debugging.

Ok... New result:

```
LWP::Protocol::implementor(/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/Net/HTTPS.pm:26):
26:         eval { require IO::Socket::SSL; };
```

Inside request() it hangs at `IO::Socket::SSL`. Means, this *script* it enough for further debug:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require IO::Socket::SSL;
```

This statement does not come back.

Further down, inside `IO::Socket::SSL` it hangs at:

```
IO::Socket::SSL::CODE(0x1274370)(/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/IO/Socket/SSL.pm:92):
92:             Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
```

Ahhhh! There is already a bugreport concerning this issue: [Net-SSLeay hangs on Suse 11 P2](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83890) pointing to [Bug #81575](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=81575) that says:

> I enountered this same issue on SLES 11 SP2, which has openssl-0.9.8j installed.
>   An upgrade to openssl-0.9.8r did resolve the problem. ...
>   The packages for 0.9.8r can be found in this repository:
>   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/fips/

Guess that's it!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Bareword `POST` should get some errors I would think. Also, why not just use the `post()` method in `LWP::UserAgent`?

Comment: No, I do not get any output. Nothing. It just hangs. Well, I just stripped down the script to these few lines. Of course I directly could use LWP::UserAgent but it has exaclty the same behaviour...

Comment: You are using `LWP::UserAgent`. I am curious why you're not using the `post()` method. And I'm curious about the `POST` Bareword, why doesn't this error out? What happens if you change that line to `$ua->post($url, Content_Type => 'text/xml', Content => $content, );`

Comment: Okokok... :) It is still the same. Now just post() does not return. Initially (as you might see from history of this posting), I posted I have a SOAP::Lite problem with exactly the same symtom. Now I could track it down that I have a LWP::UserAgent problem.

Comment: @chrsblck `->post` is just shorthand for `->request` with a method of `"POST"`. And `POST` is provided by `HTTP::Request::Common` which is an even nicer bit of sugar.

Comment: @Enkidu try using HTTP 1.1 but send the `Connection: close` header. If that makes things work, it's a keepalive problem.

Comment: @hobbs, yes I know that. I was telling him to use that to get rid of the Bareword, which I wasn't sure about. And the OP isn't stating if that was an issue. It doesn't make much since to *not* use `LWP::UserAgent` for everything except the `POST`

Comment: @chrsblck it doesn't seem like you understand at all. That "bareword" is the name of a function (which returns a request). And there's no trace of "not using LWP::UserAgent" or any issue. You're barking up the wrong forest.

Comment: @hobbs - what are you talking about? `String found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 16, near "POST`, is what I would expect from his previous code right? `(Do you need to predeclare POST?)` Is this an issue with my version of `perl`?

Comment: @chrsblck yes, or else you left out the `use HTTP::Request::Common` line or copied something else incorrectly.

Comment: @hobbs, I added "Connection => 'close'" but it did not change anything. No debug output, nothing. My script still just hangs at post().

Comment: @chrsblck in my example there is no `String found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 16, near "POST` error. But anyway, I removed `use HTTP::Request::Common` but it is still the same. Please let's come back to my real problem. How can I debug this issue?

Comment: @hobbs, @chrsblck: I started usind the debugger. And the fist line of code I see is
`LWP::UserAgent::post(/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:415):
415:        require HTTP::Request::Common;`
*lol* :)

Comment: Well... I tracked it down that it is a problem with `require IO::Socket::SSL;`. So now I am sure it is neither a problem of `use HTTP::Request::Common` nor of `LWP::UserAgent` as I originally thought. So what's the best practice to continue with this issue? Close this issue? Completly rewrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a bugreport concerning this issue: [Net-SSLeay hangs on Suse 11 P2](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83890) pointing to [Bug #81575](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=81575) that says:

I enountered this same issue on SLES 11 SP2, which has openssl-0.9.8j installed. An upgrade to openssl-0.9.8r did resolve the problem. ... The packages for 0.9.8r can be found in this repository: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/fips/

Guess that's it!